# Duality optimisation

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBZhL.png)

Questions. what does that symbol mean between Ax and b?

he has moved the b to Ax-b in the subject too section is this because all constraints have to be on one side ? if so im unsure why he has made the second line -x

for step one equation 6.6 I understand the top line. but I am unsure what he has done with the second and third line. can someone explain these ty

Comment: Isn't this defined in the textbook you took the exercise from?

Answer (score 1):

Here, $Ax \preceq b$ means $(Ax)_i \le b_i$ for all $i$ and is usually just written as $Ax \le b$.  Similarly, $x  \succeq 0$ means $x_j \ge 0$ for all $j$.

Apparently, the standard form here requires $\preceq 0$.